# Как с помощью getElementById выбрать сразу несколько элементов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать так чтобы сразу двум элементам с помощью getElementById сработала функция скрытия текста?

```js
var length = 10;

var text = document.getElementById('subscription_desc')// как сюда добавить второй элемент?

var string = text.innerHTML
var trimmedString = string.length > length ?
  string.substring(0, length - 3) + "..." :
  string

text.innerHTML = trimmedString
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <h6 style="margin:0;">Ваши подписки</h6>
    <li>

        <a href="#">
            
            <div class="channel_info">
                <h6 class="channel_title" id="subscription_desc">Секрет фирмы</h6>
                <h6 class="channel_desc" id="subscription_subtitle_desс">Оставайтесь рисковать</h6>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        
        <a href="#">

            <div class="channel_info">
                <h6 class="channel_title" id="subscription_desc" id="subscription_desc">Медуза</h6>
                <h6 class="channel_desc" id="subscription_subtitle_desc">Но есть и хорошие новости</h6>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        
        <a href="#">

            <div class="channel_info">
                <h6 class="channel_title" id="subscription_desc">Яндекс</h6>
                <h6 class="channel_desc" id="subscription_subtitle_desc">Найдется все</h6>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        
        <a href="#">

            <div class="channel_info">
                <h6 class="channel_title" id="subscription_desc">Spark</h6>
                <h6 class="channel_desc" id="subscription_subtitle_desc">Сообщество предпринимателей</h6>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
       
        <a href="#">

            <div class="channel_info">
                <h6 class="channel_title" id="subscription_desc">BOOM</h6>
                <h6 class="channel_desc" id="subscription_subtitle_desc">Твоя музыка у нас!</h6>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `Как с помощью getElementById выбрать сразу несколько элементов?` - никак

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не смотря на то, что хоть и через пятую точку, но можно вытащить элементы с одинаковым `id` (**НО НЕ С ПОМОЩЬЮ getElementById**) cамый правильный вариант использовать `class` для одинаковых групп. и использовать `getElementsByClassName` или `querySelectorAll` (для *Jquery*: `$('.MY_CLASS_NAME')`)

---

**идеалогически НЕПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ вариант**, но рабочий:

```js
var length = 10;

var text = document.querySelectorAll('h6[id="subscription_desc"]')// как сюда добавить второй элемент?

for (var i = 0; i < text.length; ++i) {
  text[i].innerHTML = 'Секрет фирмы ' +  (++i);
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <h6 style="margin:0;">Ваши подписки</h6>
    <li>

        <a href="#">
            
            <div class="channel_info">
                <h6 class="channel_title" id="subscription_desc">Секрет фирмы</h6>
                <h6 class="channel_desc" id="subscription_subtitle_desс">Оставайтесь рисковать</h6>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        
        <a href="#">

            <div class="channel_info">
                <h6 class="channel_title" id="subscription_desc" id="subscription_desc">Медуза</h6>
                <h6 class="channel_desc" id="subscription_subtitle_desc">Но есть и хорошие новости</h6>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        
        <a href="#">

            <div class="channel_info">
                <h6 class="channel_title" id="subscription_desc">Яндекс</h6>
                <h6 class="channel_desc" id="subscription_subtitle_desc">Найдется все</h6>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        
        <a href="#">

            <div class="channel_info">
                <h6 class="channel_title" id="subscription_desc">Spark</h6>
                <h6 class="channel_desc" id="subscription_subtitle_desc">Сообщество предпринимателей</h6>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
       
        <a href="#">

            <div class="channel_info">
                <h6 class="channel_title" id="subscription_desc">BOOM</h6>
                <h6 class="channel_desc" id="subscription_subtitle_desc">Твоя музыка у нас!</h6>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо за внимание! Помогло